# Problem deleting custom object

Tags: custom-object, navigation, insufficient-privileges

I can't seem to delete a particular custom object.  I am getting an error that it is in use by a Navigation Topic Item.  I have looked through my three community nagivation bars & can't see a reference to it.  I see it as a tab in Classic but don't see a way to get rid of it.  I am not sure where I should be looking for this or how to figure out where it is.  When I click on the error message, I receive an Insufficient Privileges error even though I am logged in with system admin rights.  I am including the images I am seeing.  enter image description here[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting the navigation menu option in the portal that previously pointed to the custom object that I was trying to delete.  The menu option did not currently point to the object - it instead pointed to a community page.  However, the navigation must have still had some kind of tie to the object because once I deleted the navigation option, I was able to delete the custom object.

Comment: Vou saved my life! Thanks for this answer. So sad that salesforce can not link to the place where the deletion is prevented. I would have never found it without you.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the navigation menu item that delete screen is pointing you and then remove the reference from the navigation menu and then try deleting it again .

If a custom object is referenced somewhere then the platform does not allow you to delete the object without removing the reference .

Comment: When I click on the navigation menu item link I receive the insufficient privileges page.  I have deleted custom object before - removed apex page references, etc.  I don't understand what is going on in this situation.

Comment: I would pull the metadata here via ANT migration tool or any IDE and examine the metadata and search for object reference m